# What ORM frameworks for .NET and Oracle Do You Like Best?

Tags: .net, oracle, .net-3.5, orm

What ORM frameworks for .NET and Oracle Do You Like Best?

Comment: I don't think there can be a right/wrong answer to this question : it should therefore be turned into a community wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NHibernate works best and is one of the most mature frameworks with a lot of real-world projects using it with Oracle.

Comment: I should add though that I usually need to modify or extend it a bit to suit my needs.

Comment: very well,can provide it all oracle data types and automaticly generate entity classes as like linqtosql?is there a ide for nhibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Subsonic is a small but very feature full project which enables you to get up and running with a project very quickly. It also include migrations like Ruby On Rails to keep your database up to date with your domain.

Comment: Sunsonic is light weight and pretty powerful for small-medium sized proejcts.

Answer (score 0):

[Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) all the way..

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ORM frameworks that could help you out

1. [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/)
2. [CoolStorage.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/CoolStorage)
3. [Fluent Nhibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/)
4. [Active Record](http://www.castleproject.org/ActiveRecord/)
5. [LLBLGenPro](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx)
6. [NHibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/)
7. ...
8. ...
9. ...

I have used [NHibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/) and been really happy with it, the Xml you need to create gets annoying really quickly, that's why you have [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) and [ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/ActiveRecord/) that create those mapping for you. I have yet to use [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) in my project, but I've created a project using [Active Record](http://www.castleproject.org/ActiveRecord/) and was loving it, so easy to use.

Unfortunately I've also tried the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) which simply just can't handle an Oracle database without buying a [3rd party product](http://www.devart.com/news/2008/directs475.html) for it. I tried out the [Sample Entity Framework Provider for Oracle](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider) but I didn't get it to work. So my Oracle Entity Framework experiment failed :S

There are a lot of ORM mappers out there, I've just listed a few of them and actually used only 3 of them. I would recommend googling this out and check what the community as saying about the ORM's that you like and maybe a few proof-of-concept projects before making a final decision